# Add block with observer event

Tags: event-observer, extensions, blocks

I want to add a block inside another block I have this structure:

[image]

in `config.xml` for the observer part I have this:

```
......
 <frontend>
       <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <cart_shopping>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>cart_shopping/observer</class>
                        <method>insertBlock</method>
                    </cart_shopping>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
....
```

and in observer I search for block and then I create the new block:

```
class Cart_Shopping_Model_Observer
{

        public function insertBlock($observer)
        {
            /** @var $_block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
            /*Get block instance*/
            $_block = $observer->getBlock();
            /*get Block type*/
            $_type = $_block->getType();
           /*Check block type*/
            if ($_type == 'catalog/product_price') {
                /*Clone block instance*/
                $_child = clone $_block;
                /*set another type for block*/
                $_child->setType('test/block');
                /*set child for block*/
                $_block->setChild('child', $_child);
                /*set our template*/
                $_block->setTemplate('at.phtml');
            }
        }
    }
```

my theme is rwd so:
I have put `at.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/at.phtml`

and here is  `at.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('child') ?>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

It is not adding the block, why? do I need any custom layout file or changing any `local.xml` file?! I don't know what else I should do
I tried to do observer solution with [this link](http://www.atwix.com/magento/insert-blocks/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood my problem it was in config.xml, I changed class like this:

```
 <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <cart_shopping>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Cart_Shopping_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>insertBlock</method>
                    </cart_shopping>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
```

and also I did what Amit said about the template

Answer (score 2):

Your template path location is wrong:

It should be `$_block->setTemplate('catalog/product/at.phtml');`
as you define  template location

`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/at.phtml`

**As magento every template file location is define  at layout and php code after  template/**.

**Note: you must need to use RWD Package**

As you have using `cart_shopping/observe`  that means you `have used xml pattern for call  observer class` that why `need define Model class prefix in xml`

```
  <global>
        <models>
            <cart_shopping><!-- model class prefix -->
                <class>Cart_Shopping_Model</class>
            </cart_shopping>
        </models>
    </global>
```

Comment: I don't see hello yet

Comment: should I write any code in my layout?

Comment: I +1 your answer but it did the part of problem

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to add the model definition to your config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <cart_shopping>
            <class>Cart_Shopping_Model</class>
        </cart_shopping>
    </models>
</global>
```

This will mean that the observer can use the config `cart_shopping/observer` or as you have commented you can switch to the full path `Cart_Shopping_Model_Observer`

Comment: thank you so much but I'm curious why cart_shopping/observer  did not work and <class>Cart_Shopping_Model_Observer</class> worked

Comment: because you where missing the definition that I have started but Magento can work out the model when provided with a full path even without the definition.

Comment: I got it finally, yes I did not have that one